# Can I change the liquibase source code and try to make it work for db2 z/os generateChangeLog?

Tags: liquibase

To be honest, I am not a J2EE developer, but I do some coding/scripting and work mostly on database side. My current requirement is to run liquibase's generatechangelog successfully for DB2 z/os.

But I see liquibase does not have sysibm tables in certain places, like here -> https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/snapshot/jvm/UniqueConstraintSnapshotGenerator.java

My plan here is to replace information_schema tables query with sysibm tables query (lines 309-327). Because lines 235 to line 253 might be not any use of DB2 z/os.

Not sure if the code in the following link helps identify if its DB2 z/os -> https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/database/core/Db2zDatabase.java (But it does check if it is DSN, "DSN" string for DB2 Z/OS and "SQL" for DB2 LUW i think)

Not sure I am looking in  the correct liquibase code in github, but to my best knowledge it is the link to liquibase source code.

1. I need your help to know if I am good to modify this source code and compile it for using in our environment ( I mean no legal issues in modifying source code)
2. Your suggestion if I am looking in the right place to make it (liquibase)  work for DB2 Z/OS

Please let me know in case of any queries ?

Sorry I can provide only general details .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking in the right place in general, and there are no legal issues to modifying the source code for your own use, other than those set out in the license for Liquibase. https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

It sounds like you are new to the open source world, so I would spend a little time researching how projects like Liquibase work. A good article to start with would be something like this one: https://opensource.guide/how-to-contribute/

The way that the Liquibase project is designed, you would not make changes directly to the code you found - Liquibase is designed to be extensible and work with many different database engines, so you would want to create a new set of classes that do the 'right' things for DB2/Z. You should definitely get an experienced Java developer working on this with you.

Alternatively, you might look at Liquibase Pro or Datical DB. I work for the company that produces Liquibase Pro and Datical and we have already started work to add support for DB2/Z.